# Is there a proof for this Theorem related to distributions and almost everywhere equality to 0?

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral, sobolev-spaces

I came across this theorem in one of my courses on Sobolev spaces. I am struggling to find a clear proof for it and I have not succeeded yet.

Some notation first:

$L_{loc}^{1}\left( \Omega \right) $ is the set of functions $f:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ that are locally integrable, that is
\begin{equation*}
L_{loc}^{1}\left( \Omega \right) =\left\{ f:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}%
\mathbf{;}\exists \int_{K}\left\vert f\left( x\right) \right\vert dx<\infty
,\forall K\subset \Omega ,K~\text{compact set}\right\}
\end{equation*}

$\mathcal{D}\left( \Omega \right)$ is the set of continuously differentiable functions, that is
\begin{equation*}
C_{0}^{\infty }\left( \Omega \right) =\left\{ \varphi :\Omega \rightarrow
\mathbb{R}\mathbf{;~}\varphi \in C^{\infty }\left( \Omega \right) ~\text{
and }supp(\varphi )\subset \Omega ,\ supp(\varphi )\ \text{compact}%
\right\} .
\end{equation*}

**This is the Theorem:**

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^{N}$ be an open set and $f\in
L_{loc}^{1}\left( \Omega \right) $ so that
\begin{equation*}
\int_{\Omega }f\left( x\right) \varphi \left( x\right) dx=0,\quad \forall
\varphi \in \mathcal{D}\left( \Omega \right)
\end{equation*}
Then, $f\left( x\right) =0$ a.p.t. $x\in \Omega $.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I don't even know how to start...A link to some books or links would be helpful.